# When does the equality in Schwarz' lemma hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have understood the first part of the Schwarz' lemma clearly that has been proved in H.A. Priestly's "Introduction to Complex Analysis" in the above manner. But the second part or the equality part has been left as an exercise to the reader. I think the assertion made by the author regarding the equality is not correct because at $z=0$ the equality always holds. Now if we take $f(z)=z^2$ for all $z \in B(0;2)$ then it satisfies all the conditions of Schwarz' lemma and $f(0)=0$ though $f(z) \neq 2ze^{i\lambda}$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ whenever $z \in B(0;2)$ except at $z=0$. Here's my attempt if the equality holds for some $|z_0|>0$ $:$

If there exixts $z_0 \in B(0;R)$ with $0<|z_0|=r<R$ such that $|f(z_0)|=\frac {M} {R} |z_0|$ then $|g|$ attains it's maximum at $z_0$. Since $z_0 \in B(0;R)$ and $B(0;R)$ is open so $\exists$ $r_0>0$ such that $B(z_0;r_0) \in B(z_0;R)$. But then by local version of the 'Maximum Modulus Theorem' we have $g$ is constant on $B(z_0;r_0)$ and hence by the 'Identity Theorem' $g$ is constant on $B(0;R)$. Hence $f(z)=cz$ for all $z \in B(0;R)$ where $c$ is some constant. So we have $|c||z_0|=\frac {M} {R} |z_0|$. Since $|z_0|>0$ it follows that $|c|=\frac {M} {R}$. Hence $c=\frac {Me^{i\lambda}} {R}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and hence $f(z)=\frac {Mze^{i\lambda}} {R}$ for all $z \in B(0;R)$.

Is my reasoning correct at all? Please check it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the equality holds when f=cz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct and the statement of the Schwarz lemma, as stated there, is wrong. Indeed, where it says “If equality occurs for some $z$ with $|z|<R$“, it shoud be “If equality occurs for some $z$ with $0<|z|<R$“. Your example ($f(z)=z^2$) explains why. A simpler example would consist in taking $M=R=1$ and $f(z)=\frac z2$.